# Directed graph in java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me implement the bfs on my graph?  I put my graph implementation here and the bfs algorithm to my graph . I just need some ideas how to do it.

```
public class DiGraph<V> {

        public static class Edge<V>{
            private V vertex;
            private int cost;

            public Edge(V v, int c){
                vertex = v; 
                cost = c;
            }
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "{" + vertex + ", " + cost + "}";
            }
        }

        private Map<V, List<Edge<V>>> inNeighbors = new HashMap<V, List<Edge<V>>>();
        private Map<V, List<Edge<V>>> outNeighbors = new HashMap<V, List<Edge<V>>>();
        public int nr_vertices;
        public int nr_edges;

        public String toString () {
            StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
            for (V v: inNeighbors.keySet()) 
                s.append("\n    " + v + " -> " + inNeighbors.get(v));
            return s.toString();                
        }

        public void addIn (V vertex) {
            if (inNeighbors.containsKey(vertex)) 
                return;

            inNeighbors.put(vertex, new ArrayList<Edge<V>>());

        }

        public void addOut(V vertex) {
            if (outNeighbors.containsKey(vertex)) 
                return;
            outNeighbors.put(vertex, new ArrayList<Edge<V>>());
        }

        public boolean contains (V vertex) {
            return inNeighbors.containsKey(vertex);
        }

        public void add (V from, V to, int cost) {
            this.addIn(from); 
            this.addIn(to);
            this.addOut(to);
            this.addOut(from);
            inNeighbors.get(from).add(new Edge<V>(to,cost));
            outNeighbors.get(to).add(new Edge<V>(from,cost));
        }

        public int outDegree (V vertex) {
            return inNeighbors.get(vertex).size();
        }

        public int inDegree (V vertex) {
            return inboundNeighbors(vertex).size();
        }
    }

    public void bfs()
    {
        // BFS uses Queue data structure
        Queue queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.add(this.rootNode);
        printNode(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited = true;
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = (Node)queue.remove();
            Node child=null;
            while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(node))!=null) {
                child.visited=true;
                printNode(child);
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
        // Clear visited property of nodes
        clearNodes();
    }
```

The bfs algorithm i took it from the internet, I understand it but it's for general cases, I don't know how to adapt it to my graph

Comment: What does 'some don't work' exactly mean?

Comment: isEdge() returns always YES. And inboundNeighbors() returns random nr. I can't figure it out .

Comment: Fix one error at a time via debugging. If there are so many, it's also a good idea to rethink/reread/redraft. It's like you would with an English paper, but more specificly divided into syntax and semantics. The compiler and run time output are usually very specific and give you line numbers to work with.

Comment: The problem is that I dont't know how to modify my functions to work after I have added a cost to an edge. I've put a % symbol on the rows where I get errors

Comment: You cannot use stackoverflow like this. You must leave original question. Please restore original question.

Comment: I don't understand. I can't write code in my comments, you tell me to update the question and it's not ok. So where I should put now my question?

Comment: You can update your question, but you should **add** something to it without changing the original content. Otherwise another user cannot understand what you are asking. Of course there are exceptions to this, but you should always think to the casual user that reads your question. So, add the last problem you have on this code.

Comment: I have added my problem below the original content

Comment: Perfect, I added my fixes and final considerations.

Comment: It's working. Could you explain me why the Edge class can't be declared in another file?

Comment: You can of course, remove static from declaration. I packed all in one "file" to make easier for you to execute my code. Pay attention that you could need setters and getters as well. Usually I tend to provide a copy/paste/run solution that PO can immediately verify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how to solve your problem. I preferred to paste only final solution without repeating the whole code to make it easier for you to read. If you are interested to see how the code was before, check the edit history.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19757371;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Digraph<V> {

    public static class Edge<V>{
        private V vertex;
        private int cost;

        public Edge(V v, int c){
            vertex = v; cost = c;
        }

        public V getVertex() {
            return vertex;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Edge [vertex=" + vertex + ", cost=" + cost + "]";
        }

    }

    /**
     * A Map is used to map each vertex to its list of adjacent vertices.
     */

    private Map<V, List<Edge<V>>> neighbors = new HashMap<V, List<Edge<V>>>();

    private int nr_edges;

    /**
     * String representation of graph.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        for (V v : neighbors.keySet())
            s.append("\n    " + v + " -> " + neighbors.get(v));
        return s.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Add a vertex to the graph. Nothing happens if vertex is already in graph.
     */
    public void add(V vertex) {
        if (neighbors.containsKey(vertex))
            return;
        neighbors.put(vertex, new ArrayList<Edge<V>>());
    }

    public int getNumberOfEdges(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(List<Edge<V>> outBounds : neighbors.values()){
            sum += outBounds.size();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * True iff graph contains vertex.
     */
    public boolean contains(V vertex) {
        return neighbors.containsKey(vertex);
    }

    /**
     * Add an edge to the graph; if either vertex does not exist, it's added.
     * This implementation allows the creation of multi-edges and self-loops.
     */
    public void add(V from, V to, int cost) {
        this.add(from);
        this.add(to);
        neighbors.get(from).add(new Edge<V>(to, cost));
    }

    public int outDegree(int vertex) {
        return neighbors.get(vertex).size();
    }

    public int inDegree(V vertex) {
       return inboundNeighbors(vertex).size();
    }

    public List<V> outboundNeighbors(V vertex) {
        List<V> list = new ArrayList<V>();
        for(Edge<V> e: neighbors.get(vertex))
            list.add(e.vertex);
        return list;
    }

    public List<V> inboundNeighbors(V inboundVertex) {
        List<V> inList = new ArrayList<V>();
        for (V to : neighbors.keySet()) {
            for (Edge e : neighbors.get(to))
                if (e.vertex.equals(inboundVertex))
                    inList.add(to);
        }
        return inList;
    }

    public boolean isEdge(V from, V to) {
      for(Edge<V> e :  neighbors.get(from)){
          if(e.vertex.equals(to))
              return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    public int getCost(V from, V to) {
        for(Edge<V> e :  neighbors.get(from)){
            if(e.vertex.equals(to))
                return e.cost;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Digraph<Integer> graph = new Digraph<Integer>();

        graph.add(0);
        graph.add(1);
        graph.add(2);
        graph.add(3);

        graph.add(0, 1, 1);
        graph.add(1, 2, 2);
        graph.add(2, 3, 2);
        graph.add(3, 0, 2);
        graph.add(1, 3, 1);
        graph.add(2, 1, 5);


        System.out.println("The nr. of vertices is: " + graph.neighbors.keySet().size());
        System.out.println("The nr. of edges is: " + graph.getNumberOfEdges()); // to be fixed
        System.out.println("The current graph: " + graph);
        System.out.println("In-degrees for 0: " + graph.inDegree(0));
        System.out.println("Out-degrees for 0: " + graph.outDegree(0));
        System.out.println("In-degrees for 3: " + graph.inDegree(3));
        System.out.println("Out-degrees for 3: " + graph.outDegree(3));
        System.out.println("Outbounds for 1: "+ graph.outboundNeighbors(1));
        System.out.println("Inbounds for 1: "+ graph.inboundNeighbors(1));
        System.out.println("(0,2)? " + (graph.isEdge(0, 2) ? "It's an edge" : "It's not an edge"));
        System.out.println("(1,3)? " + (graph.isEdge(1, 3) ? "It's an edge" : "It's not an edge"));

        System.out.println("Cost for (1,3)? "+ graph.getCost(1, 3));


    }
}

This is my result: 
The nr. of vertices is: 4
The nr. of edges is: 6
The current graph: 
    0 -> [Edge [vertex=1, cost=1]]
    1 -> [Edge [vertex=2, cost=2], Edge [vertex=3, cost=1]]
    2 -> [Edge [vertex=3, cost=2], Edge [vertex=1, cost=5]]
    3 -> [Edge [vertex=0, cost=2]]
In-degrees for 0: 1
Out-degrees for 0: 1
In-degrees for 3: 2
Out-degrees for 3: 1
Outbounds for 1: [2, 3]
Inbounds for 1: [0, 2]
(0,2)? It's not an edge
(1,3)? It's an edge
Cost for (1,3)? 1
```

**edit**
I have fixed `inboundNeighbors(V vertex)` and implemented `getCost(V from, V to)`. Pay attention that the second function makes sense only when you have the edge and we assume positive costs. Otherwise, we need other considerations, but I think it's better for you to post another question.

In `main` I provided you with a complete example, so, if you experiment some changes, make sure that you have the same results I had posted here. Surely all the class can be written better, but, with your experience, is better to make things simple.

Comment: The nr. of edges can be easily fixed because, there are 2 private members that I have declared nr_edges and nr_vertices. I use them to store these values. Actually the graph is read from a text file but i didn't put that part. Thank you!

Comment: How can I modify this so that each edge would have a cost?

Comment: I gave you wrong info, my bad. I edit the answer to provide you more details.

Comment: It's not working. I get a lot of errors, starting from the declaration of the Edge class :"Illegal modifier for the class Edge; only public, abstract & final are permitted" and more in the DiGraph class. I'm sorry for asking so much but I'm new to java.

Comment: put Edge declaration into Digraph one as inner class

Comment: Now it doesn't give me an error in the Edge class but when I declare neighbors it doesn't recognize V and says that Edge is not generic.

Comment: did you declare neighbors into Digraph?

Comment: Edit your question, put a bold edit on the bottom and extend the question

Comment: I have no idea how I could change my code. It's the first time I implement a graph, and even thogh at the begining it looked very easy now I think it's very complicated :(

Comment: I get errors here :neighbors.put(vertex, new ArrayList<V>());  neighbors.get(from).add(to);  return neighbors.get(vertex);   List<V> l = neighbors.get(from);